# Android Studio | Cannot build after update from Arctic Fox to Bumblebee

Tags: android-studio, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After updating I am getting this error in Android Studio:

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'lookanizer'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.2.0/realm-gradle-plugin-4.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.2.0/realm-gradle-plugin-4.2.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

With Arctic Fox version of Android it worked fine! Don't know, why it is not possible to access the url now.
Had somebody the same issue and could resolve it?

**My build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
                allowInsecureProtocol = true}
        maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
               allowInsecureProtocol = true}

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true}
        maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Do you resolve this problem, i have the some,
help pls